# How to set Soundmanager play volume at ringtone volume?

Tags: android, audio, volume

I am trying to play SoundManager using the following, but it still seams to be using the media volume instead of the ringtone volume. Why?

```
float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
mSoundPool.play((Integer) mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume,streamVolume, 1, 0, speed);
```

Comment: Which stream type did you specify when you constructed your `SoundPool` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Michael, I have to change this in "initSounds" in my SoundManager also. Thanks Michael.